# Tomcat 7 : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: tomcat7

I have installed tomcat7 in my windows xp pc and on starting the service, i cannot access `localhost:8080` in my browser and found the following in tomcat7 log files.

```
2013-05-15 15:00:30 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number 
in class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 7 requires a minimum of Java 6. The most likely cause is that you are trying to run Tomcat on Java 5 or earlier.

The alternative is that you have added something to your Tomcat install that has been compiled with a later version of Java that you are running. In this case, get a clean Tomcat install running first and then deal with the class version problem (either by running Tomcat with a later version of Java or by recompiling whatever it is you have added for Java 6 or earlier).